# iOS 9 multitasking in 70/30 hides master view

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a `UISplitViewController` in my app with the code below in it:

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController*)svc shouldHideViewController: (UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitViewController collapseSecondaryViewController:(UIViewController *)secondaryViewController ontoPrimaryViewController:(UIViewController *)primaryViewController {
    return YES;
}
```

This used to *always* show the master view and the detail view in a two-pane layout. However, on iOS 9, with 70/30 multitasking, this hides the masterview. What can I do about that?

Answer (score 0):

Note that your first delegate method was deprecated in iOS 9:

> [From the Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewControllerDelegate_protocol/index.html):
>
> Deprecated Methods
>
> splitViewController(_:shouldHideViewController:inOrientation:)
> (iOS 8.0)

If you are referring to a Normal horizontal width situation (such as on an iPad or iPhone 6 Plus in landscape) then I believe your desired layout (2 panes: master and detail, visible at the same time) is the default.